# Should the TextBox raise the validating event when Return is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm a bit confused, as far as I remember the Textbox used to launch the Validating event when the used pushed the Enter key after entering the desired text but this is not happening now.

Do you know if this is the expected behavior or not?

Thanks.

Comment: if your form has AcceptButton, then you can launch textbox validating event after Enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not as far as I remember. The TextBox generally only validates when focus is gotten/lost unless something triggers it manually.

Hvae a look at Bolu's link for a list of validating triggers

Comment: Yes, I saw that but I thought that the first way of validating a text inside a textbox was hitting Enter ... maybe was only with the DevExpress controls ... mmm thanks anyway.

Comment: AFAIK, the Validating event does *not* occur when you leave the TextBox! It occurs when you enter a control that has CausesValidation set to True.

Answer (score 2):

see:[Control.Validating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx)

Note: If the `CausesValidation` property is set to false, the Validating and Validated events are suppressed.

Answer (score 2):

I use a method similar to Javed Akram's answer, but instead of calling the Validating function, I just call focus on the parent...

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).Parent.Focus();
    }
}
```

When the TextBox itself looses focus it will call its own Validating event

Answer (score -1):

Validating event is fired when the control lost its focus, so you can fire validating event yourself in keyPress event after checking, if the entered key is **Enter** key.

**Sample Code:**

```
private void someTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            someTextBox_Validating(sender, new CancelEventArgs());
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 You should **not** be doing this. This does *not* raise the TextBox's `Validating` event. It *only* calls the method that is *named* as the event handler for the `Validating` event. Any code that lies further up the inheritance chain (i.e., in the `TextBox` class itself) will *not* be run this way.